# MINUS or NOT EXIST in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a query and want NOT to show some information

```
SELECT ?Recipe
 WHERE {
   ?Ingredient <http://linkedrecipes.org/schema/ingredientOf> ?Recipe .
   MINUS {
       <http://linkedrecipes.org/schema#Milk> <http://linkedrecipes.org/schema/ingredientOf> ?Recipe .
     }
}
```

I want to choose all Recipes where Milk is not an Ingredient

After running this query I just have an error

My data is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rcp="http://linkedrecipes.org/schema/">


<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://linkedrecipes.org/schema#Milk">
  <rcp:ingredientOf rdf:resource="http://linkedrecipes.org/schema#SaladUniqueID"/>
  <rcp:ingredientOf rdf:resource="http://linkedrecipes.org/schema#CoffeeUniqueID"/>
</rdf:Description>


<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://linkedrecipes.org/schema#Salt">
  <rcp:ingredientOf rdf:resource="http://linkedrecipes.org/schema#SoupUniqueID"/> 
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

In the result I want to have "SoupUniqueID".

Comment: What error do you get?  Your query as written is correct so knowing what error you get would help.  `MINUS` is a relatively new SPARQL feature so may not be supported everywhere

Answer (score -2):

Using a NOT FILTER will be easier.